# How to remove section header and footer view from table view?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

i am using grouped table view with single section (since i want cells in rounded rect) i want to remove table view section header and footer to save that size but its header and footer are removed but same size it maintaining......  how to solve this...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can edit size of sections header and footer in IB. Open Inspector on your table view and go to the size tab. Set there section header/footer height to minimum

Answer (score 1):

Add this code, it will resize the header and footer to zero-height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to move the Insets in the Inspector on your Table View or do it programatically. Beware that this acts different depending on the iOS system version the device is on, ie iOS 6 insets are different than iOS7 insets.

Doing it programmatically:

```
UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-35, 0, 0, 0); //iOS7 insets to line up with the navigation bar

self.tableView.contentInset = inset;
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = inset; //This is to make sure the scroll indicators are also the same.
```